# XSLT getting character count of transformed XML

Tags: xslt

I am creating some XML from an XSLT
the XML after transformation looks a little like...

```
<root><one><two>dfd</two></one></root>
```

I need to get a character count for the output (in this case would be 38).

I tried putting the whole lot in a variable then doing a string-length($vVariable) but this only brings back 3 (for the 'dfd' it excludes the characters of the tags)

Comment: Please indicate wheter you'd like xslt 1 or 2 and if attribute-value pairs should be included in the count.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do this in XSLT, but if you must do it in XSLT, you'll have to use a serializer, such as http://www.fgeorges.org/xslt/serial/. Then do a `string-length(...)` on the output of the serialization.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be very difficult to do in straight XSLT, since it's internal data model doesn't see XML elements as strings.  Although your particular example is very simple, there are multiple valid ways to serialize the same XML into text, especially when you get into namespaces.

Your best bet may be to send the result of your transformation to another tool.  If you're running the XSLT processor from the command line, you could use a tool like the linux command "wc").  If you're calling XSLT from within a larger program, you could use that language's built-in string-length functionality.